# How to override the resourcePath() function defined in Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php

Tags: laravel, overriding, laravel-6, modularization

I am modularizing laravel. I have decided to move all the default routes, controllers, resources, etc.. to /app/Modules/Pub. For the most part this has worked well. However I would like to change the default resources path of the application. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be (easily) configurable.

So... using grep I was able to track down the `resource_path()` function to `/var/www/sigma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php`

I think it's possible to override this function somewhere but this seems like a subpar hack as this function consists simply of:

```
app()->resourcePath($path)
```

Again using grep I found out that this function is to be found in `/var/www/sigma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php`

This seems to be the thing to change since it does not reference any configuration value, rather the value is hard coded:

```
return $this->basePath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'resources'.($path ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$path : $path);
```

But I think it's safe to assume it's pretty foolish to change anything under the vendor folder manually. Obviously I need to override this function somewhere. I am unclear where and how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new `Application` class which extends the `\Illuminate\Foundation\Application`:

```php
<?php

namespace <YOUR NAMESPACE HERE>;

class ApplicationCustom extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    /**
     * Get the path to the resources directory.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
     * @return string
     */
    public function resourcePath($path = '')
    {
        // Implement the custom method
    }
}
```

Now, just change your `bootstrap/app.php` file to use the custom class:

```php
$app = new YOUR_NAMESPACE\ApplicationCustom(
    $_ENV['APP_BASE_PATH'] ?? dirname(__DIR__)
);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class somewhere in your project and extend the default `\Illuminate\Foundation\Application` class. Then override the methods you need and switch the class instantiated in `bootstrap/app.php` with your custom one.